# How is the RowKey formed in the WADMetrics*** table?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I'm looking to understand the data returned by `WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20160415` table inside Azure's storage account.

It has the PartitionKey, RowKey and EntityProperties. PartitionKey, I understand. It translates to the resource Id of my resource inside the storage account. However, I partially understand the RowKey. An example RowKey is:

> :005CNetworkInterface:005CPacketsReceived__2519410355999999999

I understand the first part, which is a metric name. But what I don't understand in the number/digits that follow. I am assuming it to be the timestamp, but can't say for sure.

I was attempting to use the RowKey filter, but due to this added wrinkle it's almost impossible to generate the RowKey and use it as a filter. Does anyone know how to generate the numbers/digits in order to create a RowKey filter?

Comment: For anyone look for an answer, I circumvented this issue by not using the RowKey as a filter at all. Basically, any of the EntityProperties can be used as filters, so there was a property named `CounterName` which was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious to know about what `2519410355999999999` number is, it is essentially reverse ticks derived by subtracting the event date/time ticks from the max date/time ticks value. To derive date/time value from this number, here's what you can do:

```
        long reverseTicks = 2519410355999999999;
        long maxTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks;
        var dateTime = new DateTime(maxTicks - reverseTicks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```